# Node.js: TypeError: Object socket.io has no method 'listen'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm making a little Node app using `socket.io` 0.9.13 using Express 3.0.6. I can't seem to anything even starting to run because it says `socket.io` has no method `listen()`. Here's my code (compiled coffeescript, so it's a bit ugly):

```
(function() {
  var app, express, io, port, usernames;

  express = require('express');

  app = express();

  io = require('socket.io'.listen(3000));

  port = 3000;

  app.listen(port);

  console.log("Listening on port " + port);

  console.log('CNTRL-C to quit.');

  app.engine('hamlc', require('haml-coffee'.__express));

  app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    return response.render('index.hamlc');
  });

  usernames = {};

  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('send-chat', function(msg) {
      return io.sockets.emit('update-chat', socket.username, msg);
    });
    socket.on('add-user', function(username) {
      socket.username = username;
      usernames[username] = username;
      socket.emit('update-chat', 'SERVER', "You have connected as " + username + ".");
      socket.broadcast.emit('update-users', 'SERVER', "" + username + " has joined the chat.");
      return io.sockets.emit('update-users', usernames);
    });
    return socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      delete usernames[socket.username];
      io.sockets.emit('update-users', usernames);
      return socket.broadcast.emit('update-chat', 'SERVER', "" + socket.username + " has disconnected from chat");
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

Which raises the following error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Object socket.io has no method 'listen'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chris/src/web/kouv/app.js:8:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chris/src/web/kouv/app.js:44:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Answer appreciated greatly. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(3000);
```

Socket.io essentially hijacks the http object when it runs; express 3.xx no longer runs off the http.server though, so it's necessary to create your own instance of it for socket.io to use.

Comment: Ah... I see. `require 'socket.io'.listen(server)` was compiling to `require('socket.io'.listen(server))`

Comment: @beakr I guess @ari meant `express = require('express');` instead of `http = require('http');`

Comment: Yes, you're right! Sorry. What does `var = express()` do exactly, by the way?

Comment: @Homero https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/express.js. See lines 17 and 32-39. The createApplication function is exposed in line 17, so when express() is called, it is running lines 32-39 (setting up connect, etc.), which is saved to the variable app, and then returned to be stored in the variable app.